# How to make this ruby code more readable?

Tags: ruby

Take the sample ruby code, how to rewrite/indent it so the following ruby code to make it more readable & make sure it fits in one line i.e 80-90chars?

```
%w(survey survey_section question_group question dependency dependency_condition answer answer_type answer_validity validation validation_condition validation_prefix validation_precludes error error_type error_level error_code style style_info style_override user user_model_name user_type).each {|m| require m }
```

Reading it is painful as I have long arrays like this present all over the codebase.  it requires LOT of horizontal scrolling & I don't like that

Any way I can improve this?

Comment: This sort of question would do better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `%w` splits on whitespace, so you can insert newlines whenever you want and get the same result:

```
dependencies = %w(survey survey_section question_group question 
  dependency dependency_condition answer answer_type answer_validity 
  validation validation_condition validation_prefix 
  validation_precludes error error_type error_level error_code 
  style style_info style_override user user_model_name user_type)

dependencies.each {|m| require m }
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to how @derekerdmann did it, I *might* use:

```
%w[
  survey               survey_section       question_group       question
  dependency           dependency_condition answer               answer_type
  answer_validity      validation           validation_condition validation_prefix
  validation_precludes error                error_type           error_level       error_code
  style                style_info           style_override       user
  user_model_name      user_type
].each { |m| require m }
```

Wrapping and aligning like that is simple in Vim, using the Align plugin.

But, more likely, I'd put all the requires into a separate file and require it, much like using an include file in C to pull in a bunch of other include files. In this case, they're still being loaded, but they're out of sight. So, in a `requirements.rb` file I'd have:

```
require 'answer'
require 'answer_type'
require 'answer_validity'
require 'dependency'
require 'dependency_condition'
require 'error'
require 'error_code'
require 'error_level'
require 'error_type'
require 'question'
require 'question_group'
require 'style'
require 'style_info'
require 'style_override'
require 'survey'
require 'survey_section'
require 'user'
require 'user_model_name'
require 'user_type'
require 'validation'
require 'validation_condition'
require 'validation_precludes'
require 'validation_prefix'
```

And in my main code file I'd have `require_relative './requirements'`.

Alternately, I'd split the lists into a more manageable grouping, such as alphabetically:

```
%w[ answer answer_type answer_validity ].each { |r| require r }
%w[ dependency dependency_condition ].each { |r| require r }
%w[ error error_code error_level error_type ].each { |r| require r }
%w[ question question_group ].each { |r| require r }
%w[ style style_info style_override survey survey_section ].each { |r| require r }
%w[ user user_model_name user_type ].each { |r| require r }
%w[ validation validation_condition validation_precludes validation_prefix ].each { |r| require r }
```

It isn't as DRY as I'd like, but it's more organized and readable.

Comment: I like your example with all the require statements. That is actually not a DRY violation at all, and it is not just easy to read: it's easy to change. If you want to add `error_location`, for example, the third line of your last example would probably get too long and you'd have to reorganize, whereas the earlier example you can just add a line. It's also much easier to scan because you only have to move along one axis.

Comment: Good reasons for liking the middle example. Probably splitting the list as the first letter changes, by putting a blank line above and below, would help even more.